# Why is this code not doing its job?

Tags: c++, binary, primes

I want to create a program that writes all the primes in a file (I know that there's a popular algorithm "Sieve of Eratosthenes", but I'm trying to make it by myself). I'm trying to eliminate all the complications for the bytes that still have the value 1 then write them in a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>

void afficher_sur_un_ficher (FILE* ficher, int nb_bit);
char el_mask (int x);

int main()
{
    FILE* p_fich;
    char tab[4096], mask, eli_mask;
    int nb_bit = 0, x, f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = 0xff;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
    {
        for (mask = 0x01; mask != 0; mask <<= 1)
        {
            if ((tab[i] & mask) != 0)
            {
                x = nb_bit; 
                while ((x > 1) && (x < 16384))
                {
                    eli_mask = el_mask (x);
                    f = x / 8;
                    tab[f] = tab[f] ^ eli_mask;
                    x = x + nb_bit;
                }
                afficher_sur_un_ficher (p_fich, nb_bit);
            }
            nb_bit++;
        }
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void afficher_sur_un_ficher (FILE* ficher, int nb_bit)
{
    ficher = fopen ("res.txt", "a+");
    fprintf (ficher, "%d \t", nb_bit);
    int static z;
    z = z + 1;
    if (z % 10 == 0)
        fprintf (ficher, "\n");
    fclose (ficher);
}

char el_mask (int x)
{
    x = x % 8;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            x = 0b00000001;
        break;
        case 1:
            x = 0b00000010;
        break;
        case 2:
            x = 0b00000100;
        break;
        case 3:
            x = 0b00001000;
        break;
        case 4:
            x = 0b00010000;
        break;
        case 5 :
            x = 0b00100000;
        break;
        case 6 :
            x = 0b01000000;
        break;
        case 7:
            x = 0b10000000;
        break;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time adding all of the primes to a file... that is unless you have an infinite amount of time and an infinite amount of space :)

Comment: @Brian I assume he's doing so bounded between certain numbers?

Comment: @derrick, you say that because this is written in french ?

Comment: I guess that's because you always pass nb_bit to afficher_sur_un_fichier and nb_bit is incremented for each iteration. It only appears as a rhs except for the post incrementation.

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be a problem in the loop that's trying to clear bits indicating non-primes:

```
while (( x > 1 )&&(x < 16384))
{
    tab[i] = tab[i] ^ mask ;
    x = x * 2 ;
}
```

Since `i` doesn't change in this loop, you essentially toggling the same bit off and on while incrementing `x`.  As well as fixing the index into `tab[]`, you probably want to change the operation from xor (`^`) to something that will clear the bit unconditionally - once a bit is cleared, you don't want processing that bit again for a different factor to 'reset' the bit.  Note that a simple incrementing of `i` wont do, as the multiples of `x` in other elements of `tab` might not be in the same bit offset (indeed, a single element of `tab[]` might contain several multiples of `x`).

Even if you fix that problem, I think the loop might not be doing what you expect, since `x = x * 2;` doesn't walk `x` through its multiples - you'll end up skipping some non-primes.

Some research on how the 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' works might help.

Comment: thanks , i fix this onr but it still not doing the right job & yes its ' Sieve of eratosthenes ' but i was trying to get more primes by using bits : if u imagine that every bit is a number in the array u will get all the primes in the [4096*8] , i will edit my question & try make it more clear thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I"m missing something, but this just seems wonky. I don't remember common prime algorithms off-hand, but, for instance,

`(excerpts)
 tab[i] = 0xff ;
mask = 0x01 ;`

for (int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++)
        {
            if ((tab[i] & mask) != 0 )
 mask = mask<<1 ;

This means that you will always go 8 times - so why check with the '&'?

Another one,

`x = nb_bit ;
                while (( x > 1 )&&(x < 16384))
                {
                    tab[i] = tab[i] ^ mask ;
                    x = x * 2 ;
                }`

This just flip flops the bits on every iteration. Is that what you want?

Finally, as I don't know what you mean to do, careful with bit length of your objects. You might flip flop

0000 0000 1111 1111 ^ 0000 0001

or

1111 1111 1111 1111 ^ 0000 00001

As I don't really understand what you're trying to do, not sure this might be related.

EDIT (after Hamza's comment):

Yes. What this loop does is the following - compare/'and'

1111 1111 1111 1111

with

```
      0000 0001
      0000 0010
      0000 0100,
```

and that always will hold true. I don't know what you want to do here, but this seems fishy (changing location now with no internet for a while, but gl. :) ).

Comment: thanks , i just edit my question u may wanna read it again now  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your main function a bit:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* p_fich;
    char tab[4096] , mask;
    int nb_bit = 0 , x;

    memset(tab, 0xFF, 4096);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        for (mask = 0x01; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {
            if ((tab[i] & mask) != 0) {
                for (x = nb_bit; (x > 1) && (x < 0x4000), x<<=1)
                    tab[i] ^= mask;
                afficher_sur_un_ficher (p_fich, nb_bit);
            }
            nb_bit++;
        }
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, to address your question:
Your `afficher_sur_un_ficher` function will print whatever you pass to it, and that function is called for every loop iteration where `((tab[i] & mask) != 0)` is true.  Since you initialize every `tab[i]` byte to `0xFF`, masking off any given bit combination will always cause that `if` statement to evaluate `true`.  You are altering the value of `tab[i]`, but once you do, you no longer use that bit so it's not changing the fact that the `if` statement will always be taken.  This is why you are seeing every entry being logged.

**Edit:**
If you simplify away all the code that does not affect the decision to output or the value to output, you end up with the following:

```
memset(tab, 0xFF, 4096);
for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
    for (mask = 0x01; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {
        afficher_sur_un_ficher (p_fich, nb_bit);
        nb_bit++;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this code will print an incrementing sequence of integers (0 through (4096*8)-1) and is completely independent of the `tab` array and of the specific values of `i` and `mask`.  I think there is something missing in your implementation of the algorithm.  Do you have a link to a description of the algorithm you are trying to implement? Or is this an algorithm you developed? (Sorry, I didn't understand your description of your algorithm that you added to the question)

Comment: thanks man , all what i have is written in french but i will look for something ( sorry i coudlnt connect for the last days )
thanks again